# ipad Javascript slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, mobile

I'm looking to create a slider/scroller with javascript for the iPad. I created one using JQuery UI, but it's not supported on iPad.
I'm looking to create something simple, where the user can drag an image left and right along a track. I've looked all over the place for some simple insight on how to do that, all I find are tutorials or links to jquery plugins.
I'm not sure I can use the built-in slider from jquery-mobile, as I have specific images to use, and it doesn't look like it can be skinned.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Without any code I doubt we'll be able to help you...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use plugins? I found a link to something useful here: http://hmelyoff.github.com/jslider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery Tools Scrollable](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html) is iPad/touch friendly.

As an example, checkout the custom scrollable slider on [trekk.com](http://www.trekk.com) (works on iPad) that I built with jQuery Tools.

Answer (score 1):

I recently used a plugin called Flexslider (http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) that supports swiping between images on iOS.